# Adjust site resolution

Tags: html, css

Im doing this kind of project for highschool and I need kind of help with adjusting site resolution. Im working on my laptop and when i tried to show it to my teacher site was all... Im working on resolution 1366x768. Is there any solution that sites looks better? I tried some solutions that i found here but nothing worked... Here's my code, thank you. I'm using custom fonts so you may have some troubles seeing it good

```css
  body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 1000px;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Jocker";
    src: url("JockeyOne-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Pacifica";
    src: url("PacificaCondensed-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "ReklameScript";
    src: url("ReklameScript.ttf") format("truetype");
  }

  @font-face {font-family: "Stencil";
     src: url("Stencil.eot"); 
     src: url("Stencil.woff2") format("woff2"); 
     src: url("Stencil.woff") format("woff");
     src: url("Stencil.ttf") format("truetype"); 
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 120px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Jocker";
    margin-left: 45;
    color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }

  #jedan {
  background: black;
  }

  #dva {
  background: white;
  }
  
  .naslov1 {
    font-size: 70;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Jocker";
    color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }

  .naslov2 {
  font-size: 100;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Jocker";
  color: rgb(200, 101, 103);
  }
  
  .main2-naslov2 {
   font-family: "Stencil";
  }
  
  #header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  #navigacija {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #089DE3;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .navitem {
    background: #089DE3;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Pacifica";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
  }
  
  #navigacija a {}
  
  a#logo {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Jocker";
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .home:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
    widthL auto;
  }
  
  .shop:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
  }
  
  .getpoints:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
  }
  
  .info:hover {
    background: #00C5CD;
  }
  
  .main1 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    font-family: "ReklameScript";
    font-size: 50;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: -1500;
    right: 0px;
  }
  
  .video-container iframe,
  .video-container object,
  .video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .video-wrapper {
    width: 640px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <title>MaxSkins-Home</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Home.css" type="text/css" />
 



  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <div id="navigacija">
        <a href="Home.html" id="logo"><img src="logo.png"></a>
        <a href="Home.html">
          <div class="navitem home"><b>HOME</b></div>
        </a>
        <a href="Shop.html">
          <div class="navitem shop"><b>SHOP</b></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="navitem getpoints"><b>GET POINTS</b></div>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="navitem info"><b>INFO</b></div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h1><b>EARN POINTS,<br> GET SKINS!</b></h1>
    
 <div id="jedan">
 <div class="naslov1">How does it work?</div>
 <div class="main1"><p><b>It's simple!<br> Watch videos, do tasks and have fun!<br>After collecting large amount of coins,<br> contact us to get your skins<b></p></div></div>
 
 <div id="dva">
 <div class="naslov2">How do I get my skin?</div>
 <div class="main2-naslov2">1. EARN POINTS</div>
 <div class="main2">Once you collect enough<br>points, go to shop page<br>and choose your skin.</div>
 <div class="main3-naslov3">2. FRIENDS</div>
 <div class="main3">When you select a<br>skin, add us on some<br>of our profiles.</div>
 <div class="main4-naslov4">3. WAIT</div>
 <div class="main4">Before you get your skin,<br>you need to wait 24 hours<br>after we accept you as a friend.<div>
 <div class="main5-naslov5">4. SKIN</div>
 <div class="main5">We are sending you the<br>skin as soon as we can.<br>If you already have the skin,<br>or if you don't have champion from which you want skin from,<br> you need to choose some other skin.</div>
 </div>

 <div id="tri">
 <div class="main6">This site is not<br>associated with Riot<br>Games, inc.</div></div> 


 <div class="video-wrapper">
 <div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lwItL2NXwDw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
 <!-- /video -->
</div>
<!-- /video-wrapper --> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well you see when I open my site on some other computers(different resolution) my site doesn't look like I created it on my laptop. Is there any way to fix that? I can upload some pictures if you still don't understand :) Thanks.

Comment: Of course a website looks different on different screen sizes. That's not avoidable. Try resizing the browser window and you'll see.

Comment: I know that but etc my video container goes all the way right, not as i planed. Is there any way to I dont know for different resoultions (bigger then my) sites create auto margins so my site doesnt look like sh**...

Comment: It's up to you. You made the design decisions. To start at the very beginning, why do you have `min-width:1000px` for the `body`? What does that achieve?

Comment: If you have a specific problem you don't know how to solve, share it and we may be able to help you. For exemple, your video goes on the right because you specified `float: right`on `video-wrapper` class : you made it that way.
You can't just expect us to provide a full design for you website. It's part of the web designer's work to ensure a website displays well on any screen.